# Trying to extract my files from corrupted sd card [img file] or fix it

Tags: files

I have corrupted image file based on Ubuntu 18.04.
[Inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10LQr.png)
[Outside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9rzy.png)
It was corrupted because of update interrupt and now i cant boot it.
I have very important files on this sd but i cant extract them, because:
[I can't get access to  some folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ocmO.png)
Error:Structure need cleaning.

To solve this problem i tried:

1. [fsck.ext4 command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PY23P.png)
   But i cant execute it and in my point of view, i should be able to, because there is only 1 user with root in the system (me).My corrupted image file is read only, i can mount it only in this way

   ```
    sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/loop11 /media/sf_Jetson
   ```

Maybe i could make this file r/w ?

2. Also i tried to use sudo photorec
   [guide : https://www.handyrecovery.com/linux-sd-card-recovery/#recovery-guide]
   It recovered my files but without any system:
   [Almost useless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9MBV.png)
   [Chaos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn4E1.png)
   I just cant find my python programms in this garbadge.[Too many py files without names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbQBA.png)
3. Besides this i received advice on nividia forums: "You may chroot into the rootfs folder on your SD card with help of QEMU". With links:
   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture
   https://gist.github.com/gokart23/8ade2d431ead2de47340160301837cab
   Execute command sudo apt dist-upgrade using chroot into the rootfs folder - main idea of the suggested solution, but i couldn't get how to do that.
4. I am going to owerwrite boot folder by boot folder from sd card without corruption and try to boot it.Is it going to work?Or maybe i should overwrie multiple folders?[Picture one "inside" in the begining shows this file structure]
   And thats all.
5. Could you explain me please how to solve "Error:Structure need cleaning" and access my files, or how to execute command sudo apt dist-upgrade using chroot into the rootfs folder?Or maybe it is possible to solvethis problem other way?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details, mentioning only Linux which is supported at SE *Unix & Linux*, so why ask here?  I see nothing yet on-topic with provided details.

Comment: Just Linux edited to linux ARM64 is question correct now?

Comment: Sorry i did a mistake.Edited.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Comment: SE *Unix & Linux* does provide support for *development*, ESM, EOL, EOSS releases like Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as they fall under the *Linux* of SE *Unix & Linux*.

Comment: Just FYI: If you instead do your data forensics on Ubuntu 20.04 or later, your question would be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake.I tried to use clone of my image , located in folder in my pc,instead of sd card with my image.Now i use sd card with image and can extract all my files without any problems.Should i delete this post or shouldnt do anything?